# Can't write string from table to string attribute in C#

Tags: c#, types

I read values from an local Access mdb-file. One value is stored as string in the db and I have it in a table. When using the `GetType()` method it return "System.String" and I can print it on the console without a problem but when I want to use it as an attribute for another method (requires a string) I get an error ("Cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'" and the same for 'int'). The same problems occur with some int values.

Am I doing something wrong or what is the problem in that case?

```
Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[0][ProjName]); //prints project_name
Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[0][ProjName].GetType()); //print "System.String"

Project = new Project(dt.Rows[0][ProjName], dt.Rows[0][MinDay], dt.Rows[0][MinWeek], dt.Rows[0][DayWeek]); //Error
Project = new Project(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0][ProjName]), Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][MinDay]), Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][MinWeek]), Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][DayWeek])); //Works Fine
```

Constructor for the Project Class:

```
public Project(string projectName, int hoursPerDay, int hoursPerWeek, int daysPerWeek)
```

Comment: Your uses of `Console.WriteLine()` invoke the overload accepting a parameter of type `Object`.  This overlaod function internally calls `ToString()` on the given object value, demonstrating what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have stated in your answer is works when converting, and it is necessary as they are not strings and integers. They are objects. You can create a methid to handle it if you want.

```
public Project CreateProject(object projectName, object hoursPerDay, object hoursPerWeek, object daysPerWeek)
{
    return new Project(projectName.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(hoursPerDay), Convert.ToInt32(hoursPerWeek), Convert.ToInt32(daysPerWeek);
}
```

Comment: `projectName.ToString()` (with parens) - or OP will get another strange error :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly cast the objects:

To cast to string use:

```
Object.ToString();
```

To cast to integers use:

```
Int32.TryParse(String, out int);
```

Your constuctor becomes

```
Project = new Project(dt.Rows[0][ProjName].ToString(), Int32.Parse(dt.Rows[0][MinDay]), Int32.Parse(dt.Rows[0][MinWeek]), Int32.Parse(dt.Rows[0][DayWeek]));
```

Note: Using Int32.Parse instead of Int32.TryParse assumes that the argument provided is a valid int at all times and does not give you a way to check if the casting has succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

`dt.Rows[0][ProjName]` returns type `object`, and your method expects `string`.  Even though you know it to be a string, it is not obvious to the compiler and must be specified explicitly using a cast, as you show in your last example, although just casting should be more efficient than converting unnecessarily:

```
Project = new Project((string)dt.Rows[0][ProjName], ...
```